# problem in returning object from the .filter() function to another modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

//I tried to return messages from the .filter() to another modules. I am able to console.log() it but unable to return it. i tried returning object(manually created) from outside the .then() it worked. But when i tried to return it from inside .filter() it didnt work. is it a problem of asyn? please explain on the basis of this problem about how async/await to use here... p.s i have read some documentation about promises, async/await.. but am not clear enough to use it in practical way.

```
function loadChat() {
 return model
    .find()
    .then((data) => {
      data.filter((datas) => {
        messages = datas.messages;
        console.log(messages);
        return messages;
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    });
  // const ans = {
  //   name: "madhav",
  // };
  // return ans;
}
```

//calling modules code is here

```
messages = loadChat();
  console.log("type of messages", typeof messages);
  console.log(messages);
  //emitting event to load previous chat

  socket.emit("loadChats", loadChat());
```

//output

```
type of messages object
Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: You need to `return model` and `return data.filter((datas) => {`.

Comment: i got promise {<pending>} returning model and data.filter(....

Comment: i got promise {<pending>} returning model and data.filter(....

Comment: Read the duplicate question.

Comment: i solved it by returning .model and .filter and resolving promises(async/await) in the calling module .. thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see the problem now. You need to properly pass data from the find function - It should look something like this:

`model.find((data) => data.filter ... // The rest of your code)`
Also, what kind of error message or console log are you getting?

Comment: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null.. i got this error ..if i replace the code as u suggested... in my original code i got 'undefined' returned to my calling module